# WP Rest API upload image

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, http-post, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to upload image via Wordpress REST api v2. So far all I managed was to create empty entries in wordpress media library. Meaning they have image names, but no actual image.

POST Request:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/media

Authorization: Basic d29yZHByZXNzOndvcmRwcmVzcw==
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=map2.jpg

{
  "source_url" : "file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/map2.jpg"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 127,
  "date": "2016-05-25T08:43:30",
  "date_gmt": "2016-05-25T08:43:30",
  "guid": {
    "rendered": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/map2-3.jpg",
    "raw": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/map2-3.jpg"
  },
  "modified": "2016-05-25T08:43:30",
  "modified_gmt": "2016-05-25T08:43:30",
  "password": "",
  "slug": "map2-3",
  "status": "inherit",
  "type": "attachment",
  "link": "http://localhost/wordpress/map2-3/",
  "title": {
    "raw": "map2-3",
    "rendered": "map2-3"
  },
  "author": 1,
  "comment_status": "open",
  "ping_status": "closed",
  "alt_text": "",
  "caption": "",
  "description": "",
  "media_type": "image",
  "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
  "media_details": {},
  "post": null,
  "source_url": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/map2-3.jpg",
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/media/127"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
      }
    ],
    "about": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/types/attachment"
      }
    ],
    "author": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
      }
    ],
    "replies": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=127"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get no errors, everything's seem to be working, except response->**post** and response->**media_details** is either null or empty. Ofcourse image itself is not uploaded.

Based on this [GitHub WP-API Adding Media](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1768) ticket, I should send 2 requests. First `POST` request should return data with post object. I would send this post object via `PUT` method, and image should be uploaded...since I have no post object, this is not possible.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20):

Sideloading images is not supported by the wordpress api so you will have to do some changes.

First, your [content-type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) should be **image/jpeg** and not **application/json**, remember that content-type is supposed to reflect the data that you are passing and the POST media request expects an image.

Another change you have to make to accommodate the content-type is the way that you are passing the data. Instead of sending it with the source_url parameter, try passing it as a binary file.

One last thing I would mention is that the wp/v2 calls return 3XX status on a few occasions. It would be useful to follow those redirects and redo those requests to those new urls.

I had some issues passing JPEG images but PNG images have worked well. Here is a curl example that I use to upload png media:

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://www.yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media \
--header "cache-control: no-cache" \
--header "content-disposition: attachment; filename=tmp" \
--header "authorization: Basic d29yZHByZXNzOndvcmRwcmVzcw==" \
--header "content-type: image/png" \
--data-binary "@/home/web/tmp.png" \
--location
```

Comment: Thanks. Your callout about the content-type helped me fix an error I was experiencing.

Comment: @rtrigoso I can upload the file but WordPress does not recognize it as an image. I can see that the file size is some 300KBs. What might be wrong? PS: I am sending the file as base64 encoded data string.

Comment: I actually require two calls. One for the Creation & Upload of the image; other for Adding the `-d`ata fields. None of those calls can make the image as Featured in the given `"post":"$post_id"`, presumably requiring a third call...

Comment: @rtrigoso i tried with same header as you written in your post and pass binary data but unable to create media. Done through Postman. Its only return list of all media

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for a JS solution, here's how I made it work using Axios. I will skip authorization implementations, as there are a few options around (oAuth, JWT, Basic).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

axios({
  url: 'http(s)://{your-wp-domain}/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename="file.jpg"',
     Authorization: {your-authorization-method},
    'Content-Type':'image/jpeg'
    },
    data: fs.readFileSync('path/to/file.jpg', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
})
 .then(res => {
   console.log(res.data);
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
 });
```

Comment: Can you share the request body to be sent ?

Comment: I don't think this will work, as `fs` is not available in browser.

Answer (score 5):

My working answer using PHP cUrl

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$data = file_get_contents('C:\test.png');

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://woo.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/media",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic XxxxxxxXxxxxXx=",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.png",
    "content-type: image/png",
  ),
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the response that you get after execute this request ?

Comment: Thumbs up for the curl_setopt_array. Never seen it before and wasn't quite aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

At january 2020 using wordpress 5.3.2 with nginx the solution that work for me is:

```
 function uploadFile($token, $archivo) {
    $file = file_get_contents( $archivo );
    $mime = mime_content_type( $archivo );
    $url =  BASEAPI. 'wp-json/wp/v2/media';
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: '.$mime,
        'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($archivo).'"',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' .$token,
    ] );
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
}
```

The token is the Authorization JWT token and $archivo is the path to file.

Comment: CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Here you can use this code snippet. This works for me using Wordpress API REST

```
<?php
//Add this to your function.php
function upload_image( $imageID, $login ) {
  $request_url = 'https://DOMAINNAME.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media'; //change the domainname
    $image_file_path = get_attached_file($imageID); //change this to your file meda path if your not throwing media file to other server
  $image = file_get_contents( $image_file_path );
    $mime = mime_content_type( $image_file_path );

  $api_media_response = wp_remote_post( $request_url, array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $login ), //login format USERNAME:PASSWORD
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='.basename($image_file_path).'',
            'Content-Type' => $mime
        ),
        'body' => $image
    ) );

  //this function return wp_remote_post
  // more info => https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the usage ?

Answer (score 2):

After trying to get the image upload running with wp_remote_post (don´t wanna use curl for several reasons) i came up with the following working solution:

```
// Upload image to wordpress media library

$file = @fopen( 'image.jpg', 'r' );
$file_size = filesize( 'image.jpg' );
$file_data = fread( $file, $file_size );
$args = array(
    'headers'     => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'USERNAME:PASSWORD' ),
        'accept'        => 'application/json', // The API returns JSON
        'content-type'  => 'application/binary', // Set content type to binary
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=nameoffileonserver.jpg'
    ),
    'body'        => $file_data
    );



$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'http://myserver.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media', $args);
```

Comment: Clean, simple and straightforward - can be used for other languages such as C# with some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload a image to WordPress rest API using nuxtjs or vuejs you can use the below code:

**in template:**

```
<input style="display: none;" type="file" @change="onFileSelected"
<button @click="onUpload" />
```

**in data:**

```
  data() {
return {
  selectedFile: null,
  previewImage: null
};}
```

**in methods:**

```
  onFileSelected(event) {
  this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
   }

   onUpload() {
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
fd.append("title", "pedram");
fd.append("caption", "this is caption");


/* file reader for prview image */
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile);
reader.onload = e =>{
                this.previewImage = e.target.result;
};
/* set request header */
const headers = {
  'Content-Disposition':`attachment; filename=${this.selectedFile.name}`,
   Authorization: "Bearer" + this.$cookiz.get("AdminToken"),
  'content-type': 'image' 
};

  this.$axios.post('/wp-json/wp/v2/media', fd, { headers })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

if you want to preview the image you can use file reader and store it in a data variable then use the data instead of image src like bellow code:

```
<img @click="$refs.fileInput.click()" v-if="previewImage" :src="previewImage" alt="" class="w-100" />
```

It took me one day to solve the issue I hope the above codes helps