# WP REST attachment

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

How do I attach images and videos on my post via WP REST API?
I was trying via `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3372/meta` including form-data key and value (images) but returns the following

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot view this post.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post

Answer (score 0):

WPAPI Official has a [good article](http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/guides/2016/08/15/create-a-post-with-featured-media.html) about this.

You need to do the following two steps.

1. [Upload media via REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#create-a-media-item). This is done in a POST request, for more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397480/3381997) .
2. If you wish to set the uploaded media as featured image, include the media id in `featured_media` field in your POST request, see [this doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post).
3. If you wish to attach image in to content of a post, then you'll need to create an image tag in content html. Like

   `<img src="linkToUploadedMedia">`